# Does every non-empty quasigroup have a left or right identity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, quasigroups

I know that some quasigroups are not loops, meaning they don't have a two-sided identity. But are there non-empty quasigroups that don't even have one-sided identities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quasigroup may be [identified with a latin square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasigroup#Latin_squares) by viewing the latin square as its "multiplication" table.

The task is then just to exhibit a latin square of size $n\times n$ with symbols $1,\ldots,n$ in which no row or column repeats the symbols in that order.  To do so one may modify a latin square by permuting the rows and columns as one wishes.

For example:

$$ \begin{array}{c|ccc}
 * &   1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
\hline
 1 &   1 & 3 & 2 \\
 2 &   3 & 2 & 1 \\
 3 &   2 & 1 & 3 \end{array} $$